# Degenerate perturbation theory of a two-dimensional harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory

In short: how should one develop perturbation theory, when all the values $\langle a | \delta H | b \rangle$ vanish in some manifold of degenerate states $a$, $b$?

A more concrete and longer discussion follows.

Consider an isotropic two-dimensional harmonic oscillator along $x$ and $y$ directions. Going to polar coordinates, we have that the lowest energy state is $|n=0, m=0\rangle$ and has the energy $E_{00}=\hbar \omega$, whereas the next
two states $|n=0, m=\pm1\rangle$ are degenerate and have the energy $E_{00} = 2\hbar\omega$.

Now add a linear perturbation along a certain axis, e.g., $\delta H=-Fx$ to the Hamiltonian. A correction to the ground state can be computed in the usual manner by utilizing the non-degenerate perturbation theory.

It seems that a correction to the states $|n=0, m=\pm1\rangle$ must be computed using the degenerate perturbation theory. The usual prescription is to form a matrix $V$ with elements $V_{ab} = \langle a | x | b \rangle$, where $a$ and $b$ are the states $|n=0, m=\pm1\rangle$, and to diagonalize this matrix $V$ in order to lift the degeneracy with respect to this concrete perturbation. The prescription does not seem to work in this case, since $V_{ab} = 0$ for each $a$ and $b$.

The physical meaning is clear: we should have worked in the Cartesian basis, and then the perturbation would have applied only to the $x$ harmonic oscillator, and not $y$. Then the problem of degeneracy would not have arisen.

How does one proceed formally in such pathological cases in general, and in this case in particular? Is there a way to lift the degeneracy? Does $V_{ab} = 0$ in general signal that one is fine with disregarding the degeneracy?